# Are subdomains on blog sites "real"?

Tags: web, subdomain

Everybody has seen a blog. They usually follow the syntax of: `user.site.com`

But are those subdomains REAL, or are they just hidden by `mod_rewrite`s in the `.htaccess` or something?

Also, does having many subdomains on a server slow it down? I've gotten mixed answers for these questions.

I am thinking of making a blogging website, and I want to know if my users should have REAL subdomains, or just have the subdomains point to another page.

Comment: What qualifies as a REAL subdomain? Aren't all subdomains real? Or are you just discarding the case of a wildcard subdomain?

Comment: what is a wildcard subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by REAL subdomains? A subdomain is just a domain that can be added to the main domain. Take, for example, *yahoo.com*. They can make *games.yahoo.com* or anything else they want!

Subdomains don't really lag your site, I have never experienced that anyways, and they are a very common thing so I don't believe it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What would it mean for a subdomain to be "real" or not?

You can safely have hundreds of thousands or millions of subdomains hosted on a single web server. What matters most is overall system traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The domains don't have to be purchased and registered individually as when you buy a domain name (example.com, example.org, etc.) you essentially have the right to add an arbitrary number of subdomains to it and point them anywhere you please.

The domains are real in the sense that the site's DNS settings have to be configured so that the user's browser knows where `sub.domain.com` points to. Most sites with a format like you mentioned have set up "wildcard" DNS rules so that requests to `(anything).example.com` will point to the same place, at which point the requests are sorted out by either a script on the server or the server configuration itself by means of virtual hosts.

The scenario you describe I think would be best handled if you set up a wildcard record on your domain to point `*.example.com` to a single location on your server, and then set up a script in some programming language at that location to display the right information according to what that domain says.

The following tutorial gives a good run-down of how to do exactly that using Apache server and PHP with CodeIgniter. if you're not programming with PHP or you don't want to use CodeIgniter, the principles remain the same and the tutorial can be generalized from fairly easily.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

As long as the subdomain does not exist you can mask the URL and have it perform an action based on a user entering the 'fake' sub domains path.

This is possible ONLY when you include code like the following to the top of your index.php at the `document_root`.

```
<?php
$mask = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ( $mask == "http://blog.blogsite.com/" ) {

    // Do whatever you want
    header( 'Location: https://www.blogsite.com/' );
}
?>
```

Alternatively you could create a new iframe for that specific user, instead of sending them to the main site.